# Is the JavaScript promise handler determined by the order of its functions?

Tags: javascript, promise

```
exports.userDidSignOut = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    const userId = data.userId;
    const settingsUpdate = {
        "fcmToken": null,
    };
    const promise = admin.firestore().collection("user-settings").doc(userId).update(settingsUpdate);

    promise.then(
        (_value) => {
            return null;
        },
        (reason) => {
            return console.log(reason);
        }
    );
});
```

I'm working with a database (Firestore) that returns a promise when data is updated. In this snippet above, I update the database with `update()` and it returns a `value` parameter on success and a `reason` parameter on failure. Because I can rename these parameters freely, how does the promise know which function is the success and which is the error? Is it purely based on the order they appear? And can I remove the `value` parameter entirely and will the promise know that's the function to call on success?

```
promise.then(
    () => {
        return null; // is removing the parameter of this function safe to do?
    },
    (reason) => {
        return console.log(reason);
    }
);
```

Comment: *Is it purely based on the order they appear? And can I remove the value parameter entirely and will the promise know that's the function to call on success?* Yes

Comment: The name of a parameter of a function is always arbitrary. JS will not check what the name of parameter of a callback is and decide how to call it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance and so then there can only ever be 2 functions in this promise handler, correct? Is there ever a scenario where a third exists?

Comment: Yes, only two. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Two for the standardized implementation, at least. Other implementations might vary, like `$q`'s [optional progress handler](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisethenonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress).